# FMDB EXC_BAD_ACCESS when inserts to database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fmdb

Im getting this error when im trying to insert something in my database:

[image: fmdb error]
The strange thing is, that the error only occurs when there is about 12-14 previus records in the table that im inserting to. Anyone that knows how to solve this?

Here is my code:

```
 - (void)addToBasket:(id)sender {
   NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
   NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MainDatabase.db", docDirectory];

   databasePath = filePath;

   db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:databasePath];
   if (![db open]) { [db release]; return; }

   NSInteger prodID = ((UIControl*)sender).tag;

   [db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO order_items VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", @"", [NSNumber numberWithInt:prodID], orderID, [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], nil];

   [basket insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:prodID] atIndex:0];
   [basketQA insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] atIndex:0];
   [basketItemName insertObject:@"test" atIndex:0];
   [basketPrice insertObject:@"test" atIndex:0];

   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
   [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

   [db close];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What type is `orderID`?  Where is it coming from?  Are you sure it's not a dangling pointer?  You are only supposed to pass objects into `executeUpdate:`.

Also, you are over-releasing `db`.  Unless a method has `new`, `alloc`, `retain`, or `copy` in the name, any object returned is autoreleased.  You don't have to release it yourself.

Comment: The type of the orderID is a NSNumber, but as you said, i over-released the `db` which i think caused the errors. It is finally working now after removing  `if (![db open]) { [db release]; return; }`.  Thank you!

Comment: I ran into the same error message and I couldn't catch any error with zombie and all that. And it was because I didn't know I am suppose to pass only objects! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You don't show where `orderID` is defined, but if it's not an object (derived from `NSObject`) then that will break in the code you have shown.  If it's a primitive integer type then you need to wrap it in an `NSNumber` object as you have done with the other values:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:orderID]
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn on [zombies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode), see what happens.